# Knockout.js - Keep posting date/time always updated

Tags: datetime, time, knockout-2.0, auto-update

I wonder how can I keep the date of publication always up, as do the Twitter, Facebook sites using a Knockout lib. Follow the example:[image]

The update is "taken" as time passes.

Sorry if there is already something about it, I'm not sure what that's called, much less how to do a search on Google, I did not return me the expected results.

Comment: You can use setInternal in a custom binding to refresh the text and use moment.js for the formatting: http://jsfiddle.net/P638h/1

Comment: Many thanks for their time! But how do I format the same way as in this picture? I need only what already has passed since the posting (seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years). Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go, using [SugarJs](http://sugarjs.com/features#date) for date parsing

```
var updateInterval = 5 * 1000; // update every 5 seconds
var postDate = new Date();     // this supposed to be the post date

function model() {
    var self = this;
    this.relativeTime = ko.observable();
    setInterval(function() {
        self.relativeTime( Date.create( postDate ).relative() );
    }, updateInterval);
}

ko.applyBindings( new model() );
```

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anasnakawa/Eh96H/)**